# $14$ different balloons and $10$ (different) kids

Tags: probability

I have $14$ different balloons and $10$ different kids.
What are the odds that exactly $6$ kids get a balloon?
A 0.1512
B 0.0002
C 0.0959
D 0.6306

I know that I need to divide by $10^{14}$ (all the options).
I also know I need to multiply by $10C6$ (picking the $6$ kids).
From this point, I am having trouble thinking of a way to calculate the rest (with out counting any case more than once).

Thank you

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done thus far is correct.

Once the six children who will receive the balloons have been selected, we have to exclude the possibility that fewer than six children receive a balloon.  For that, we need to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $6^{14}$ ways to distribute the $14$ balloons to the six selected children.  However, this counts distributions in which not all the children receive a balloon.

There are $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to select a child not to receive a balloon and $5^{14}$ ways to distribute the balloons to the other children.

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select two children to not receive a balloon and $4^{14}$ ways to distribute the balloons to the other children.

In general, there are $\binom{6}{k}$ ways to select $k$ children to not receive a balloon and $(6 - k)^{14}$ ways to distribute the balloons to the other children.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways of distributing the balloons to exactly six children is 
$$6^{14} - \binom{6}{1}5^{14} + \binom{6}{2}4^{14} - \binom{6}{3}3^{14} + \binom{6}{4}2^{14} - \binom{6}{5}1^{14}$$

Hence, the probability that exactly six of the children receive a balloon is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{10}{6}\left[6^{14} - \dbinom{6}{1}5^{14} + \dbinom{6}{2}4^{14} - \dbinom{6}{3}3^{14} + \dbinom{6}{4}2^{14} - \dbinom{6}{5}1^{14}\right]}{10^{14}}$$